# Jquery loop through json array data fetch with comma separed?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, ajax

I have json array and I am trying to fetch the array values with comma separated. Mysql query and loop through json array

```
if($_REQUEST['grpid']) {
    $sql = "SELECT cnumber, group_id FROM tbl_contact WHERE group_id ='".$_REQUEST['grpid']."'" ;
    $resultset = $connecDB->query($sql);
    //$resultset = mysqli_query($connecDB, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($connecDB));

    $data = array();
    while( $rows = $resultset->fetch_assoc() ) {
        $data[] = $rows;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
} else {
    echo 0; 
}
```

**JS :**

```
$("#gnumbers").change(function() { 
  var id = $(this).find(":selected").val();
  var dataString = 'grpid='+ id;    
  $.ajax({                
    url: 'getGroupNumbers.php',
    dataType: "json",
    data: dataString,  
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {  
      var i, l;
      for (i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) { 
        $("#num").text(data[i].cnumber);
        //console.log(data[i].cnumber);
      }       
    } 
  });
});
```

Result display only last row. Below is the output :

[image]

I want, how can I all **cnumber** data with separate by comma in my textarea?

Comment: [`.text( text )`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2) -> `Set the content of each element in the set of matched elements to the specified text`. Your issue is that `$("#num").text(data[i].cnumber);` is in a loop, where each iteration overwrites the previous. You need do do an `.append()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `.text()` to `.append()` on each iteration of the loop, after the 1st.

```
success: function (data) {  
  var i, l;
  for (i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) { 
    if(i==0) { // if 1st, use .text()
        $("#num").text(data[i].cnumber);
    } else { // if not 1st, use .append() and prepend a comma
        $("#num").append(", "+ data[i].cnumber);
    }
    //console.log(data[i].cnumber);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Sean it's working.Can you tell me how can I do if I checked it's all selected and if unchecked it's all removed or unselect? (same event etc)

Comment: Even I also remove double qoute with str_replace my code is: $json_string = json_encode($data);
 $json_string = str_replace('"','',$json_string);
 echo $json_string;
and output like this: [{cnumber:8801752992444,group_id:3},{cnumber:8801795978968,8801936761915,group_id:3}]

But my result does not display with same for loop. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try :

```
var values = [];
$("#gnumbers").change(function() {
  var id = $(this).find(":selected").val();
  var dataString = 'grpid='+ id;    
  $.ajax({                
    url: 'getGroupNumbers.php',
    dataType: "json",
    data: dataString,  
    cache: false
  }).done(function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i,e) {
      values.push(data.cnumber);      
    });
    $("#num").append(values.join(','));
  }).fail(function () {
    // Fails
  });
});
```

Set an array called `values` here, and learn the results in this array. Also, you should use the correct syntax for ajax calls. See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).